# UserControl Custom Properties for Triggers

Tags: wpf, triggers, dependencies, styles, custom-properties

I am writing a custom user control, called MyUserControl. I have many DependecyProperties for it, which I use in the MainWindow where several MyUserControl are defined multiple times. What I would like to know is how can I create custom Properties that the Triggers/Properties for a style would fire?

For example, if I have a custom property BOOL IsGoing and a custom property MyBackgroung(the background of the UserControl), both defined as :

```
public bool IsGoing
    {
        get { return (bool)this.GetValue(IsGoingProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(IsGoingProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsGoingProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsGoing", typeof(bool), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(false));  

public Brush MyBackground
    {
        get { return (Brush)this.GetValue(MyBackgroundProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(MyBackgroundProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyBackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "MyBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Red));
```

and if I define my UserControl in MainWindow.xaml, how can I access the Triggers and set MyBackground, depending on whether or not the IsGoing property is true/false?
I tried many things, but in essence, I'm trying to achieve something like:

```
<custom:MyUserControl MyBackground="Green" x:Name="myUC1" Margin="120.433,0,0,65.5" Height="50" Width="250" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  >
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsGoing" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="MyBackground" Value="Yellow"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </custom:MyUserControl>
```

I hope my explanation is good enough for you to understand. I've been working on this for a couple of days now, and I can't seem to find the solution. 
Thanks for the help!!!

Adrian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your style should just need to be used as `UserControl.Style` and have the correct `TargetType`, also default values you intend to change via trigger need to be moved into the style due to [**precedence**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
<custom:MyUserControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="custom:MyUserControl">
        <Setter Property="MyBackground" Value="Green"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsGoing" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="MyBackground" Value="Yellow"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</custom:MyUserControl.Style>
```

Whether this actually *does* anything depends on how you use the properties in the control definition.

Comment: Thanks !!!! It worked :) ... Wow, I just can't believe it was that simple. After struggling with it for a few days, and to be virtually the same thing, only with a couple of lines modified ... I can't believe it ... THANKS!